# Two forms to choose from, choose only one

Tags: forms, web-app, input-fields, options

I've got one screen with two API options available (web tool). Both forms include a title and two input fields. The user can only choose one API at the time.

Now, I've tried checkboxes, a dropdown menu to show only one, a tab nav (and that's odd). I've tried to disable the other option's input fields when editing the other... etc. None of them are solutions.

I am drawing blanks. How would you guys solve this?

[image]

Comment: Can you share some screens of what you tried already?

Comment: Hi Rob. I've added a blanco screen of the situation. Stripped of any branding for obvious reasons.

Comment: Why not tabs like the main menu ?

Comment: "None of them are solutions." Why not?

Answer (score 65):

You could use an **[accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/).** Here's an example of one I've used before:

[image]

Comment: Looks nice and clean. If necessary, you could also have a short summary in the "closed" option(s) if the title alone isn't enough to give context.

Comment: As an alternative to an accordion, it could be boxes side by side, traditional HTML fieldset-like structures, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 options you can try here:

1. **Two step approach**: in the first step they choose which API, they click Next, and in the next step they configure the settings. When you do this initially the UI is similar to a wizard, but once it's set and you want to change your setting, the UI needs to change because you'd want to see the settings and not the wizard again.
2. **Drop down approach**: Initially only the drop-down is visible. Once they choose the API they want from the drop-down, its settings appear below it. The drop-down stays visible, and if they change its value, the UI of the settings change.

Personally I would choose the drop-down approach because the UI stays the same for initial setup and future changes.